Using different types of conjunctions
Is that true that only "when" is used to show that the actions was already ongoing? Let me explain

When I got home she was listening to the music.( she started before I got home)

After/Once/The moment I got home she was listening to the music (I'm pretty sure it is wrong without "when")


I think conjunctions from my second example would only work to show one action after another for instance

After/ once/ the moment I got home I ate diner

To sum up, Am I right that 2 example also requires "when" and that my other conjunctions only work to show one action after another?

I fail to see how these conjunctions would not be the same in your language.

She was listening to music as I arrived.  She was listening to music while I worked.

But what do you mean by (the ungrammatical) "the actions was"? Both?

It's not "when" that tells us that the action was already ongoing - it's the continuous verb form of she was listening to the music. Compare When I got home she cooked dinner and When I got home she was cooking dinner. It's the same word "when" in all cases.

@FumbleFingers I know all you say. Just tell me if my 1 example would alsi be correct and with the same meaning if I used once or after or the moment instead of when?

You can't use once or after with an ongoing action, so ?Once I got home she was listening to the music and ?After I got home was listening to the music are both invalid. Note that we don't normally include the definite article in She was listening to music. But we always include it in She was listening to the radio, and it's often included in She was watching [the] TV.

And what about "the moment"?


Is that true that only "when" is used to show that the actions was already ongoing?

No, it's not true. It depends on the action:

When she arrived, I left.

That denotes an event (her arrival), and a corresponding action at that point in time.

The phone always rings when I'm cooking.

In this case, the event is the phone ringing during an ongoing action (cooking).
Of course, you can also use "while" to denote an ongoing action, eg "someone called me while I was cooking".

I think the sense of the question is the opposite: are the other conjunctions prohibited when referring to a continuous action (using past perfect "was Xing")?
